# How to join two unrelated tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables:

Table 1: Formulas

```
FormulaId    Formula Text
1            [Qty] * [Rect]
2            [Qty] * [Al]
3            [Mt] * [Cat]
```

Table 2: Context

```
ContextId    Name
1            Test 1
2            Test 2
3            Test 3
4            Test 4
```

I need to join those somehow in sql server 2008 R2 to get a table where for each context id I will have a full list of formulas, i.e.

Result

```
ContextId    Name     FormulaId    Formula Text    
1            Test 1   1            [Qty] * [Rect]
1            Test 1   2            [Qty] * [Al]
1            Test 1   3            [Mt] * [Cat]
2            Test 2   1            [Qty] * [Rect]
2            Test 2   2            [Qty] * [Al]
2            Test 2   3            [Mt] * [Cat]
3            Test 3   1            [Qty] * [Rect]
3            Test 3   2            [Qty] * [Al]
3            Test 3   3            [Mt] * [Cat]
4            Test 4   1            [Qty] * [Rect]
4            Test 4   2            [Qty] * [Al]
4            Test 4   3            [Mt] * [Cat]
```

Answer (score 29):

You want to use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT FormulaId, Formula, ContextId, [Name]
FROM Formula
CROSS JOIN Context
```

Comment: I've got to get better at typing on the phone.  Autocorrect doesn't seem to understand SQL.

Answer (score 24):

You can use the [`Cartesian Product`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two tables as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Formulas, Context
```

This would result in `M * N` rows.

Comment: How can I pull specific columns from two completely unrelated tables?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try [`CROSS APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select *
from context
cross apply formulas
order by contextid
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53fe4/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can only do Cross Join. Other joins can be done only with related tables.