# inserting sql with loop

Tags: sql, loops, sql-insert

I have the table `PERSONAL`

```
ID_PERS   NAME 
---------------
11         azerty
22         uiop
```

and the table `TOURNE_LABEL`

```
ID_TOUR   NAME 
--------------
1         w
2         p
3         v
```

I want to loop over all of `person` and then join it with `tourne` and insert to a new table.

I have created empty table LS_PDA

```
ID_PERS   ID_TOURN
-------------------
11         1
11         2
11         3
22         1
22         2
22        3
```

how can I do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719266/how-to-join-two-unrelated-tables-in-sql

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

SQL is all about set based operations. If you're thinking about a loop, chances are you're heading in the wrong direction. For this problem, you could cross-join the tables, thus producing all the possible combinations, and use the insert-select syntax:

```
INSERT INTO ls_pda
SELECT      id_pres, id_tour
FROM        personal
CROSS JOIN  tourne_label
```

Comment: thanks you, but there are no relation between ID_PERSON and ID_TOURN....

Comment: @Soft8Stev not sure what you mean. Can you explain how this output is wrong?

Comment: @Soft8Stev just saw your edit. I'll revamp my answer.

Comment: @Soft8Stev See my edited answer. A `cross join` should do the trick for you.